# MDX Filter a dimension with another dimension

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssas, mdx

To all excuse my ignorance, but I'm new to MDX  below is the query I'm trying to run

```
 SELECT 
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Task Burn Down] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { ([Calendar].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Priority].[Priority Code].[Priority Code].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS 
FROM ( 
 SELECT 
  ( { Filter([Calendar].[Date].AllMembers, [Calendar].[Date].CurrentMember <= [Sprint].[Sprint].CurrentMember.Properties("Stop Date")) } ) ON COLUMNS 
 FROM ( 
  SELECT 
   ( { [Sprint].[Sprint].AllMembers } ) ON COLUMNS 
  FROM ( 
   SELECT 
    ( { [Team].[Team].AllMembers } ) ON COLUMNS 
   FROM [Backlog2]
  )
 )
) 
WHERE ( [Team].[Team].&[27], [Sprint].[Sprint].&[9] ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

When I run this I expect to get 1 value for [Measures].[Task Burn Down] for each day of the month.   But I only want one month.  My Sprint dimension has a stop date and I do not want to return any values after the stop date.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems my only problem was I forgot to process the dimensions of the cube.  Oops, sometimes these things happen.  I have the query above working.